# SwiftUI passing @Published viewmodel object value to @Binding

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to updating view with SwiftUI and binding.
I have a MainView that observes changes in ViewModel.
I would like this view to respond to changes in **viewModel.data.image**. I don't know how to pass a value to HeaderView.

Currently this code refuses to compile. I get an error:

```
Value of type 'ObservedObject <LockedCourseViewModel> .Wrapper' has no dynamic member 'course' using key path from root type
```

View:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HeaderView(image: $viewModel.data.image)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {    
    @Published var data: Model?
    
    func fetchData(id: Int) {
        // fetching some data from api
        self.data = Model(data: data)
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: URL
}
```

HeaderView:

```
struct HeaderView: View {
    @Binding var image: URL?
}
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

As your `Model` is also a class, you don't need Binding, pass instead reference to entire model and use image from it.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // once data is fetched HeaderView will be updated
        HeaderView(model: viewModel.data ?? Model())
    }
}
```

and

```
struct HeaderView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    // ... other code
}
```

**Update:** alternate with binding to image

```
var body: some View {
    let boundImage = Binding(
        get: { viewModel.data?.image },
        set: { viewModel.data?.image = $0 }
    )
    return VStack {
        HeaderView(image: boundImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: What if HeaderView is used in other views where I don't use this model?

Comment: See updated with used proxy binding and original HeaderView.